# Is it correct to ask "What special in me"?

Tags: word-choice

Someone ask me to me on Facebook to see me (yes, I know it's strange), I asked him back

> "why, what is special **in me**"

.

Comment: I'd probably use "so": "What's **so** special in me?" or "about me?".

Answer (score 2):

Saying "Why, what is special in me" does make sense but it probably is not something you would say as it sounds strange.

You would probably say 
"Why, what is so special about me?"  Asking them why they have chosen you for something or want to choose you.

Or "Why, what do you see in me?" using see in me to ask why they picked you.

Both would be equally valid.